# Add Product by Category in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to insert my product by category in django. I have two model Product and Category. I want to add Product in Product table.when I add product category comes in select box and select category. Category id in category value. which is insert in product table. Category is ForeignKey. But show this error: **Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Category: Mixeur>, <Category: Hachoir>, <Category: Batteur>]>": "Product.category" must be a "Category" instance.**

model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label
```

view.py :

```
def add_product(request):
    print(request.POST)
    p_category = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':

        label = request.POST['label']
        description = request.POST['description']
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        category = request.POST['category']

        data = Product(
            label=label,
            description=description,
            quantity=quantity,
            category=p_category
            )
        data.save()


        return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/')
    else:
        form = AddProduct()

    return render(request, 'product/add_product.html', {'form': form, 'p_category':p_category})
```

add_product.html

```
<form action="/add-product/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="label">Label: </label>
    <input id="label" type="text" name="label" value="">

    <label for="description">Description: </label>
    <input id="description" type="text" name="description" value="">

    <label for="quantity">Quantity: </label>
    <input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="">

    <select class="form-control mb-4" name="category">
        <option selected disabled>Select Category</option>

        {% for cat in p_category %}
        <option value="{{cat.id}}">{{cat.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}

    </select>

    <!--    {{ form }} -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is to add a QuerySet to the ForeignKey field. That's why you're getting an error.

```
def add_product(request):
    p_category = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':

        label = request.POST['label']
        description = request.POST['description']
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        category = Category.objects.get(id = request.POST['category'])

        data = Product(
            label=label,
            description=description,
            quantity=quantity,
            category=category
            )
        data.save()


        return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/')
    else:
        form = AddProduct()

    return render(request, 'product/add_product.html', {'form': form, 'p_category':p_category})
```

I assigned the category related to category.objects.get() from the id information to the category variable and sent it to the Product class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a primary key which cann be referenced as foreign key in the Product table try creating a fiels id as primary key in whichever kind of sql you are using then set
id= models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
then you can reference the following on your product table

Comment: pls feel free to ask for further clarification